# CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization() not working

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am trying to use location services in my iOS app but for some reason `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` is not working. When the user first uses the app, the prompt comes up as normal asking for permissions but then when you open the app a second time, for some reason `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` method is not called so I cannot display the user current location on the map.

My code is below:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    var config:NSURLSessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    config.URLCache = NSURLCache(memoryCapacity: 2 * 1024 * 1024, diskCapacity: 10 * 1024 * 1024, diskPath: "MarkerData")
    markerSession = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
 }



 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {

        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        mapView.delegate = self
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
     }
 }
```

Comment: After use accepts the location access, it is stored (unless the user manually went into the settings and disabled it and renable while your app is running). The second time you launch the app, the location is already allowed so it did not change, so your delegate method will not be called. Why don't you just have `mapView.myLocationEnabled = true` outside the `didChangeAuthorization` delegate method ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First you need to add `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` or `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`(if you want to use in background) in your info.plist file. See the following image:

[image]

Next, in your swift file, you need to call either `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` or     `locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()` in your `viewDidLoad()` method.

Finally, you can do a `mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: locations.last!.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)` in your locationManager delegate method.

Sample code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager();

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86,
            longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6)
        var mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
        self.view = mapView

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            print("iOS >= 8.0.0")
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        println(locations.last)

        var mapView = self.view as! GMSMapView

        mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: locations.last!.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
    }
}
```

You can will [this post](http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/), for more details about LocationManager change in iOS 8.