# Google maps SDK wont ask for location in Swift project

Tags: google-maps, swift

I have integrated Google maps SDK with a Swift project and I am able to run the app and get the map however I am asking the user for their location but nothing comes up. I think I have added everything correctly:

NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in plist and:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    var locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location.coordinate
    println("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
}
}
```

Comment: Does the `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)` get called? If so, you should be fine. You can try to add the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` too in your info.plist. Also, you can try to delete and install your app again. You can check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28680623/4195406) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for that. Turned out my map view/scene didn't reference the class however your link provided additional functionality. Thanks :)