# ioS Google map v2 not working - my location cannot be got

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am working on iOS app using Google Map SDK. I try to set on the CLLocationManager to get location of my device for 10 seconds and right bottom button to get my location instantly. When it comes to the implementation, the app show no response to initiate the method startUpdatingLocation to get my location. Would you please tell me the way to use locationManager to finish the aim?

The following is my working :

```
-(bool)isNetworkAvailable
{
    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
    SCNetworkReachabilityRef address;
    address = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(NULL, "www.apple.com" );
    Boolean success = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(address, &flags);
    CFRelease(address);

    bool canReach = success
    && !(flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionRequired)
    && (flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable);

    return canReach;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];
  //  [self getTime];

    if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
        NSLog(@"Please enable location services");
        return;
    }

    if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        NSLog(@"Please authorize location services");
        return;
    }


    if([self isNetworkAvailable]){
        NSLog(@"connected ");
    }else {
        NSLog(@"not connected ");
    }
    CarArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    float latitide = [defaults floatForKey:@"lati"];
    float longitude = [defaults floatForKey:@"longi"];
    NSString *desp = [defaults objectForKey:@"desp"];


    NSLog(@"assadsd arrived map");
    if(latitide!=0.00&&longitude!=0.00) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitide, longitude);
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(position.latitude, position.longitude);
        camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latitide  longitude:longitude  zoom:12];
    }else{
        camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:22.2855200   longitude:114.1576900  zoom:12];
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.2855200, 114.1576900);
    }
    if(desp.length > 0 ){
        marker.title = desp;
    }
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;


    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest ;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 5.0f;


    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
      marker.snippet = @"HK";
    marker.map = mapView_;
    mapView_.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite;
    mapView_.delegate = self;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    });
    mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;
    mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;

    [mapView_ addObserver:self
               forKeyPath:@"myLocation"
                  options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                  context:NULL];


    self.view = mapView_;

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    NSLog(@"assadsd configured d map");

}



- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        NSLog(@"Please authorize location services");
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"CLLocationManager error: %@", error.localizedFailureReason);

    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);

    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]     initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"application_name", nil) message:NSLocalizedString(@"location_error", nil) delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"ok", nil) otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [errorAlert show];

    return;
}

-(void) handleDoubleTap {
    NSLog(@"location double tap ");
}
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}



// CLLocationDelegate
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

        // Optional: check error for desired accuracy

         CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
         NSLog(@"location x :  %f"  , location.coordinate.longitude);
        NSLog(@"location y :  %f"  , location.coordinate.latitude);
        NSDate* eventDate = location.timestamp;
        NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
        [manager allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:CLLocationDistanceMax timeout:10];


        if (markera == nil) {
            markera = [[GMSMarker alloc] init] ;
            markera.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake( location.coordinate.latitude ,  location.coordinate.longitude );


            markera.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.97f); // Taking into account walker's shadow
            markera.map = mapView_;
        }else {
            markera.position = location.coordinate;

        }


    GMSCameraUpdate *move = [GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:location.coordinate zoom:17];
    [mapView_ animateWithCameraUpdate:move];
```

}

Comment: you must use or `[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];` or `requestAlwaysAuthorization `

Comment: You have to make sure you add the ` NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` or `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in your info.plist file. Also call `[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]` or `[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]`. You can see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28680623/4195406) for more details.

Comment: still not working after adding these into pinfo.list

Comment: I have found that my bundle is of version 1.8.0 , ios 8 not supported, how to download the latest version of GOogle Map SDK BUndle ?

Comment: Here's how to install Google map SDK. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start  At the end of article they have a guide on how to upgrade from your version to the latest.

Comment: I cannot install rvm and hence rubygem. All links go ComnnectionTimeout
see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31016422/ios-getting-my-location-regularly-and-setting-button-to-get-my-location-google